# How to pass cookie to subdomain in Apache

Tags: reactjs, apache, cookies, proxy

Lets assume I have project on .NET and is required to develop frontend for some additional module on ReactJS. According to requirements, I can login only on backend side (it has it's own UI) and frontend on React should be a standalone application. I can authorize on frontend side with backend API by passing cookies (that I get after login on backend) in Header.

I have placed source code to /var/www/project so there is such structure:

/var/www/project/backend - .NET serves to 127.0.0.1:5000

/var/www/project/frontend - I have generated a static build from ReactJS to /var/www/project/frontend/index.html

My Apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName project.com

        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName subdomain.project.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/project/frontend/

        <Directory "/">
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Backend works and I can access it at project.com. Frontend works also on subdomain.project.com. But I need backend to path cookie (e.g. http://prntscr.com/lgfikx) to frontend (where currently is http://prntscr.com/lgfjlx)

I have tried ProxyPassReverseCookiePath, ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain, Set-Cookie, but failed. Probably I have just used it wrong, but I have not found anywhere a working example. Answers on similar questions have not worked for me.

My final goal is to authorize frontend so I could talk to backend API. Can somebody tell me the best or just any working solution of how to do it?

Comment: Can you please make some larger screenshots where you show the domain column or if you'd rather not tell us the real domains, at least tell us which domain the cookies are set to (with the project.com, subdomain.project.com monickers)
If your cookies are set for 127.0.0.1 or localhost instead of project.com, you have to use the ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain because your backend isn't aware of it's domain.

Comment: Ok, so here are cookies for backend (i.e. project.com) - http://prntscr.com/lhhfrb
And here are cookies for frontend (i.e. subdomain.project.com) - http://prntscr.com/lhhzqg 

BTW there is an error in console: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://project.com/api/module/validatesession' from origin 'http://subdomain.project.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" does not help :(

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the correct cookie in the WebDev tools, it's most likely that you set the cookie to HttpOnly and didn't make it available to JavaScript in the first place.

If your backend is aware of the domain name used (the cookies it sets should say .project.com in the Domain column of your web developer tools and not 127.0.0.1 or localhost), your frontend app should be able to access the cookies as well.

You only need the ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain if your backend server is using a different domain name than the one the reverse proxy uses. (i.e.: backend lives at domain.com, but you're accessing it through a reverse proxy at project.com)